# Why do some Chrome apps install themselves as extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

When looking through my Chrome extensions list (`chrome://chrome/extensions/`), I noticed that some of the apps I have installed have also installed themselves as extensions.

### Example

`Google+`

Here is the [Google+ Webstore page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google%20/dlppkpafhbajpcmmoheippocdidnckmm):

[image: Google+ Webstore page, showing installed app]

It mounts its self as and app as you would expect on the "New Tab Page":

[image: Google+ App Icon]

However, I noticed on the extensions page, it is there too:

[image: Google+ on the extensions page]

The [View Website](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google%20/dlppkpafhbajpcmmoheippocdidnckmm) link on the extensions page for Google+ just takes me to the store page and the extension installs and uninstalls with the app, leading me to believe that it is just part of the app.

What I want to know is, **what do they do for the app?**  I was thinking it might be something like offline synchronisation, however Google+ does not have this feature as of yet to my knowledge.

Exactly the same issue happens with the app **[Scratchpad](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scratchpad/kjebfhglflhjjjiceimfkgicifkhjlnm)**

Comment: These are what Google [calls hosted apps](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/apps_vs_extensions). More often than not, they're just pointers to the website, often placed for discovery and publicity.

Comment: @Sathya, But there are still differences in behavior between hosted apps. Why is this so? See http://superuser.com/q/925410/78897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some apps their functionality requires that they have a presence while you use the browser for other sites. For example, if you want to share a picture with Pinterest app/plugin, the app needs to scan for pictures and add the context menu or icon for the user to be able to tag them. [This link](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/apps_vs_extensions) might be of some help for apps v.s. extensions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The Google Developers link was perfect.