# Why do some hosted Chrome apps appear under chrome://extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

All Chrome ([hosted apps](https://superuser.com/questions/483233/why-do-some-chrome-apps-install-themselves-as-extensions#comment573180_483233)) Apps get listed under `chrome://apps`. Some examples: 'Google Drive', 'Google Search', and 'Youtube'.

However, some Chrome Apps **also** get listed under `chrome://extensions`. Some examples: 'Google Docs', 'Google Sheets', and 'Google Slides'.

What's causing Chrome Apps to be listed under `chrome://extensions`?

What are the **differences** between  apps that appear under `chrome://extensions` and those that do not?

Comment: I think this is a specific question for Google, themselves. I don't know if many people on SU would be able to answer with any degree of certainty.

Comment: @CanadianLuke, This isn't a Google question, It's a Chrome question. Why do some Chrome apps appear under chrome://extensions? Why would that even happen?

Comment: The way it was worded, and with the examples you gave, it looked like it was just based on Google apps, which led to the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The apps you mentioned also have extension versions which are generally by default auto enabled with the apps version

Comment: I don't think this is right. Do you mean that I actually have a 'Google Slides' app plus a 'Google Slides' extension? If they are indeed separate entities, why is it that removing the 'Google Slides' app actually removes the 'Google Slides' extension and vice-versa?

Comment: Because you (and most users) dont use the apps OUTSIDE of chrome so they slaves to the extension for functionality IN the browser   nearly every dev app /extension exhibits samw behaviour by default